# PCA with result non-interactively in R

Tags: r, pca

I send you a message because I would like realise an PCA in R with the package ade4.

I have the data "PAYSAGE" :

[image]

All the variables are numeric, PAYSAGE is a data frame, there are no NAS or blank.

But when I do :

```
require(ade4)
ACP<-dudi.pca(PAYSAGE)
2
```

I have the message error :

```
**You can reproduce this result non-interactively with: 
dudi.pca(df = PAYSAGE, scannf = FALSE, nf = NA)

Error in if (nf <= 0) nf <- 2 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:

In as.dudi(df, col.w, row.w, scannf = scannf, nf = nf, call = match.call(),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion**
```

I don't understand what does that mean. Have you any idea??

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sharing a data set/example others could access, if possible. This seems data-specific and with `NAs introduced by coercion` you may want to check the type of your input - `typeof(PAYSAGE)` - the manual for `dudi.pca` states it takes a data frame of numeric values as input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example :

```
ag_div <- c(75362,68795,78384,79087,79120,73155,58558,58444,68795,76223,50696,0,17161,0,0)
canne <- c(rep(0,10),5214,6030,0,0,0)
prairie_el<- c(60, rep(0,13),76985)
sol_nu <- c(18820,25948,13150,9903,12097,21032,35032,35504,25948,20438,12153,33096,15748,33260,44786)
urb_peu_d <- c(448,459,5575,5902,5562,458,6271,6136,459,1850,40,13871,40,13920,28669)
urb_den <- c(rep(0,12),14579,0,0)
veg_arbo <- c(2366,3327,3110,3006,3049,2632,7546,7620,3327,37100,3710,0,181,0,181)
veg_arbu <- c(18704,18526,15768,15527,15675,18886,12971,12790,18526,15975,22216,24257,30962,24001,14523)
eau <- c(rep(0,10),34747,31621,36966,32165,28054)

PAYSAGE<-data.frame(ag_div,canne,prairie_el,sol_nu,urb_peu_d,urb_den,veg_arbo,veg_arbu,eau)

require(ade4)
ACP<-dudi.pca(PAYSAGE)
```